# Recovering a missing page number

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, pagestyle

In formatting my Ph.D thesis (report document class) it is required that the first page of the TOC ("Table of Contents") contains just a page number and a "Page" located at the right-lower side of the "Table of Contents", while in the subsequent page of TOC, there should be a CHAPTER header right aligned and Page header left aligned on top of each subsequent page in the TOC. However, the use of `\fancyhf` combined with `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}` eliminates the page number in the first page of TOC (which I want to preserve). I also tried to change `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}` to `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{plain}` but in that case the first page also contains the "CHAPTER header right aligned and Page header left aligned" which I only want to enforce starting from the second page of my TOC (my TOC is a 3-pages TOC). Is there a way to achieve my desired formatting requirement? Thank you for your help and this issue has driven me crazy... Edit: I have to make sure that the "TABLE OF CONTENTS" should only appear at the first page of TOC... Not in the subsequent pages of TOC....

```latex
{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\rhead{Page}
\lhead{CHAPTER}
\tableofcontents}
%\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill Page\par}
```

I also attached the relevant generated first page of the TOC below. The ideal situation is that I can make the first picture below to have the number iii located at the bottom center of the first page of TOC.
[image]
[image]

---

Edit: Using the idea provided by Pieter van Oostrum, I got the followings. However, it is required that "The margin should be 1 inch at the top of pages iii-xiv. The headers should be below, just touching the 1 inch margin line." May I know how can I adapt Pieter van Oostrum's code so that this requirement is fulfilled as well? Thanks!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just removing the `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}` or any variant thereof and not redefining pagestyle `plain` should give you only the page number on the first page of the TOC.

Comment: As I said, if I simply remove that line I got the same thing as shown in the second picture above. i.e., the CHAPTER left header and the Page right header wil show up in the first page of TOC...

Comment: OK, then this must be a peculiarity of the thesis class. Which class are you using? And I'll look into this later.

Comment: There is a `\usepackage{asudis}` line which uses the `asudis.sty` file (which can be googled, see for instance here https://github.com/shumway/asudis/blob/master/asudis.sty) Thank you very much!

Comment: Dear Fei: I feel that you can request your University to hand you a sample LaTeX document of any of their accepted PhD dissertations and you work with that model! Best wishes..

Comment: @Dr.Sundar I tried but failed, there is no "expert" in the "dissertation format team" at ASU...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[image: d]

Using the code of [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637669/161015) now start your document as

```
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\normalsize  \centering TABLE OF CONTENTS \par \medskip \hfill Page} % ToC title

    \pagestyle{TOC} % use TOC style
    \pagenumbering{roman} % roman numbering
    \setcounter{page}{3} % start with iii
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage% needed to start a new style<<<
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES} % this title to to add to ToC
    \pagestyle{FIG}% use FIG style
    \listoffigures

    \cleardoublepage% needed to start a new style<<<
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \pagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: Hello I actually didn't get what I want (as you showed), with your code everything looks even worse in my document... As I said my TOC is a 3-pages TOC but the layout of the first page is different from the subsequent pages of TOC...

Comment: Also even if you used `\renewcommand` I didn't see where it is used...

Comment: @Fei Cao Thank you for your feedback. To advance in the solution: (1) If you compile just  my answer in your system you get the desired result for the ToC and LoF? (2) Do you mind if I provide you with a replacement package asudis later?

Comment: Dear Simon, thank you very much! Pieter van Oostrum's code already helped me a lot so I guess until the dissertation formatting team informs me that further modifications are necessary I do not plan to touch that anymore, I have just thrown too much time on it...

Comment: @Fei Cao Glad you find a solution. Thank you for your feedback and good luck with your thesis!

Comment: Thank you very much as well!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I have adapted the spacing and the headers on following TOC pages. Experiment with the numbers in two the lines indicated with `<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<` to adjust to the requirements or your taste.

The package `asudis` does some weird things with the layout of the TOC. It uses `\pagestyle{fancyplain}` which is deprecated. And then it changes the headers in the second page with `\afterpage`, but not on the following pages. This is done in the macros `\@cfttocstart` and `\@cfttocfinish` so I disable these and use my own code.

This is a minimal example that uses the rest of `asudis.sty` but with my header definitions for the TOC. You may use similar code for the list of tables/figures if you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{dcolumn,array}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{asudis}
\usepackage[pageanchor=true,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,bookmarks,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

\newcommand\LB[1]{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{#1}} % not used anymore
\fancyhf{}

\fancypagestyle{toc}{
  \fancyhead[L]{CHAPTER}
  \fancyhead[R]{Page}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@cfttocstart}{%
  \newgeometry{top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,includehead,includefoot}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \doublespace
}
\renewcommand{\@cfttocfinish}{\restoregeometry}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\title{Your Title Goes Here}
\author{Your name}
\maketitle
\newpage
\mbox{}
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{toc}
\doublespace
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill Page\\[-0.3in]\par} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this is not I want, the "TABLE OF CONTENTS" should only appear at the first page of TOC... Not in the subsequent pages of TOC....

Comment: Just remove the `\fancyhead[C]{\contentsname}`

Comment: Thank you, I will upload the document to see if the "dissertation format team" is OK with this version. In my look, the spacing between the "FIGURE" header ("Page" header as well) and the top content in the LIST OF FIGURES are slightly different across different pages of LIST OF FIGURES (the first page of LIST OF FIGURES has a larger/normal spacing while starting from the second page the spacing is a little bit narrow). If they are OK with this version I will accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Can you also adjust the spacing issue? The staff in our University want "The margin should be 1 inch at the top of pages iii-xiv. The headers should be below, just touching the 1 inch margin line."  Thank you so much!

Comment: I have edited to code to get the new spacing. You can adjust the numbers to get things right if it still isn't good enough.